# How can I disable my javascript onclick button on another div?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I disable my javascript onclick button event on another div that is located inside a main div which contains my id. Here is the code:

```
 <div id="clickme">

 <div id="disabled_clickme">hello</div>

 </div>

 $('#clickme').click(function () {
 //SOME CODE
 }
```

How can I disable my clickme function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, the click event is triggered in the child nodes and then propagated to their parents. This is called [event bubbling](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/what-does-event-bubbling-mean/).

You can use the `stopPropagation` method in the event object from `#disabled_clickme` click to prevent it from reaching `#clickme`.

```
$('#disabled_clickme').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/PUTTQ/

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to find the stopPropagation for function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.off()`

```
$("#clickme").off();
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/ -- Calling `.off()` with no args removes all event handlers for the specified selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickme').click(function () {
    // SOME CODES
});

// disables click event
$('#disabled_clickme').click(function(){return false;});
```

The result of this is that if you click the `<div id="disabled_clickme">` it will not return any codes. BUT if you click the `<div id="clickme">` the codes for that will still work.